# For Twitter: how to get a user's oauth_access_token client-side like facebook, for server side integration

Tags: javascript, facebook, twitter, oauth, twitter-anywhere

I'm trying to do server-side posting of facebook and twitter posts. So, you click a button: if you're not connected it allows you to connect and opens a dialog overlay to allow you to post a facebook/twitter post; if you are connected it just opens the overlay. Facebook works because I can get all the oAuth keys easily client-side and then pass them to the server. How do I do this in Twitter?
(PS: this is a fully AJAX site so I can't count on page refreshes)

In facebook I do this:

```
        if (FB) {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    $.getJSON(window.page.services + "StoreAuthToken", { type: "facebook", socialId: response.authResponse.userID, authId: response.authResponse.accessToken, expiresInSeconds: response.authResponse.expiresIn }, null);
                    window.dialogs.loadFacebookOverlay({ href: href, image: image, description: description, socialId: response.authResponse.userID });
                } else {
                    FB.login(function(response) {
                        if (response.status === 'connected') {
                            $.getJSON(window.page.services + "StoreAuthToken", { type: "facebook", socialId: response.authResponse.userID, authId: response.authResponse.accessToken, expiresInSeconds: response.authResponse.expiresIn }, null);
                            window.dialogs.loadFacebookOverlay({ href: href, image: image, description: description, socialId: response.authResponse.userID });
                        } else { /* user cancled */ }
                    }, { scope: 'share_item' });
                }
            });
```

How do I get the auth token, maybe using twitter @anywhere code?

```
        if (twttr) {
            twttr.anywhere(function(T) {
                if (T.isConnected()) {
                    /* how do I get the auth token here? */
                    window.dialogs.loadTwitter({ href: href, image: image, description: description });
                } else {
                    /* a pop-up is blocked - any way to allow it? */
                    T.signIn();
                }
            });
        }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Also asked here: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/14405

Comment: I've made some progress. Now all I need is the auth token so I can do my server-side stuff.

I call the anywhere function like this
    $(window).bind("load", function(e) {
        if (twttr) {
            twttr.anywhere(function(T) {
                window.twitter = T;
            });
        }
    });

Then I can call the signIn() without the pop-up being blocked. The problem is that the when I call window.twitter.bind("authComplete", function(e, user) { /* user data doesn't have the auth token */ });
Now, how can I get the auth token now that I'm connected?